# apt-get 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: apt, internet

I'm using my school network, and it seems that only `apt-get` is blocked, regardless of which server I use. `pacman` and `rpmdrake` work fine, both of which I've tested with Chakra and Mageia respectively.

How is this block executed? Is there a way to bypass this block without using a proxy (proxy's too slow)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They execute the block by proxying all of your school's data through a filter. Anyways, have a look at this guide to setting up a proxy for apt:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy